# nth-child not working using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hello Fellas i am trying to use nth-child in my code but its not working following is my code

**HTML**

```
<ul class="colour" >
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.colour ul li:nth-first-child(1)').css('color','pink');
});
```

I don't know why its not working plz help guys

Answer (score 3):

`nth-first-child` is not a pseudo-selector, `nth-child` is.

You're also selecting `.colour ul` which looks for a `ul` that is a descendant of an element with the class `.colour`. That won't work with your markup. You'd want just `.colour` or `ul.colour`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Vsc2/)

In response to your comment, you'd want to use `nth-last-child` in that scenario, which does exist. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UtDns/)

Comment: what if i want to stylize second last <li>

Answer (score 1):

You should use following:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.colour ul li:nth-last-of-type(2)').css('color','pink');
});
```

This will select second last element.
Here is the [more tutorial.](http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-of-type-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already awesome answers above, you can use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), if the number of those `li` items is gonna stay constant.

```
<ul class="color">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

And the JS:

```
//The indexing starts from 0, like in arrays
$('.color li:eq(0)').css('color', 'pink');
```

Hence the second last can be accessed as:

```
$('.color li:eq(5)').css('color', 'pink');
```

Just my 2 cents!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stylize the second last `<li>`, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.colour li:nth-last-child(2)').css('color','pink');
});
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UqH87/)</kbd>